# Вопрос по поводу @media

Tags: css, вёрстка

Везде пишут о том, что @media необходимо писать в конце css файла.
**Почему?**
У меня есть структура (Sass) типа:

```
@import "variables"
...
@import "assets/file"
@import "assets/file2"
...
```

file/file2 содержат отдельные секции сайта, по типу хедер, футер и т.д.
И свои @media я пишу в конце этих файлов.
Потом они собираются gulp-ом в один большой `.css`

**Плохо ли это**, и если да, то чем чревато ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, если файлы адекватно разделены, то это нормально.

Дело в том, что @media не влияет на мощность css-селектора, поэтому если она будет идти раньше такого же селектора, то решающее значение будет иметь не её правило, а последнее. Если же файлы разделены в соответствии с логической структурой и написаны хорошо, то проблема со случайным затиранием стилей из media-запроса возникнуть не должна.

Comment: Спасибі большое!